# Integrating Mobile SDK in existing React Native app

Tags: mobilesdk, react-native

We have an existing React Native application that we would like to integrate with the Mobile SDK.

Is this something that we can do?
Is there a recommend way to do this?
Is there any specific requirements that our existing app needs for this work?

Comment: [Create a React Native app with Mobile SDK](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/mobile_sdk_react_native/mobilesdk_reactnative_create_app)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **CocoaPods** this can be easily done for IOS as below.

You will need to install the Cocoapod first

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Create a default pod file if you do not have one

```
pod init
```

Make sure you have pod file as [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Templates/blob/dev/ReactNativeTemplate/ios/Podfile)

Now run the below command to get all dependencies

```
pod install
```

> If this fails with errors mentioning xcrun, make sure that in Xcode in Preferences > Locations the Command Line Tools are assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer , I believe the below step might help you.
you can manually add the Salesforce SDK to your project
create a new folder called mobileSDK
and add in the iOS [sdk][1] and Android [SDK][2] from salesforce

preferred way is just add a new file for each ios and android

For android create a new file in project root call it "installandroid.js"
then paste the below code and save it

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var packageJson = require('./package.json')
var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

console.log('Installing npm dependencies');
execSync('yarn install', {stdio:[0,1,2]});

var rimraf = require('rimraf');

console.log('Installing sdk dependencies');
var sdkDependency = 'SalesforceMobileSDK-Android';
var repoUrlWithBranch = packageJson.sdkDependencies[sdkDependency];
var parts = repoUrlWithBranch.split('#'), repoUrl = parts[0], branch = parts.length > 1 ? parts[1] : 'master';
var targetDir = path.join('mobile_sdk', sdkDependency);
if (fs.existsSync(targetDir)) {
    console.log(targetDir + ' already exists - if you want to refresh it, please remove it and re-run install.js');
} else {
execSync('git clone --branch ' + branch + ' --single-branch --depth 1 ' + repoUrl + ' ' + targetDir, {stdio:[0,1,2]});
    rimraf.sync(path.join('mobile_sdk', 'SalesforceMobileSDK-Android', 'hybrid'));
    rimraf.sync(path.join('mobile_sdk', 'SalesforceMobileSDK-Android', 'libs', 'test'));
    rimraf.sync(path.join('mobile_sdk', 'SalesforceMobileSDK-Android', 'libs', 'SalesforceReact', 'package.json')); // confuses metro bundler
}
```

similarly create a file called "installios.js" in the root of the project and paste the below code and save it

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var packageJson = require('./package.json')
var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

console.log('Installing npm dependencies');
execSync('yarn install', {stdio:[0,1,2]});

console.log('Installing sdk dependencies');
var sdkDependency = 'SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS';
var repoUrlWithBranch = packageJson.sdkDependencies[sdkDependency];
var parts = repoUrlWithBranch.split('#'), repoUrl = parts[0], branch = parts.length > 1 ? parts[1] : 'master';
var targetDir = path.join('mobile_sdk', sdkDependency);
if (fs.existsSync(targetDir)) {
    console.log(targetDir + ' already exists - if you want to refresh it, please remove it and re-run install.js');
} else {
    execSync('git clone --branch ' + branch + ' --single-branch --depth 1 ' + repoUrl + ' ' + targetDir, {stdio:[0,1,2]});
}

console.log('Installing pod dependencies');
execSync('pod update', {stdio:[0,1,2], cwd:'ios'});
```

Then go to terminal or command prompt , point to your project root folder
then execute the below commands

> node ./installios.js

Once its completed then run

> node ./installandroid.js

Hope this helps to make the salesforce integrated in your app.

But unfortunately I am unable to help you up with code changes in the code level
[1]: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS
[2]: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android